# Selenium Java Chrome can't click button

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i am learning Selenium i need some help. okay i was working with [This](http://nostyle%20mobile-magnifier)
website . here is use case :

1. Enter Text in search bar (Done)
2. Press Search Button. (Not Done)

I have tried with className to click button but it is not working

```
//then this method to search 

void invokeChrome(){
    try{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\software testing\\chromedriver.exe");
        web = new ChromeDriver();
        web.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        web.manage().window().maximize();
        web.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        web.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        web.get("https://www.coursera.org");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am using Chromedrive 74 and selenium : 3.9.0 release

Comment: Did you got `compound class` exception when ran the test?

Comment: yes : org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Comment: @supputuri sometimes i get this exception as well. i am sorry i am new to selenium , if asking lame questions : `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nostyle mobile-magnifier` is not a single class, it has 2 classes so you are getting `compound class` exception when try with `By.className`. So change that line as shown below using xpath.

**Xpath:**

```
 web.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Enter Search'] [2]")).click();
```

Comment: Try this out and let me know still you get the exceptions.

Comment: yes i tried both of them , it is giving `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`

Comment: after writing text inside search bar , it stuck there and give `timeout` exception

Comment: Got it. There are 2 elements that match with xpath and the first one is hidden so we are not able to click on it. Try with the updated answer it's working for me in python.

Comment: Yes it is working thank you so much, can you recommend me which language is trendy for selenium testing. java or python . also can you recommend me some good links to learn basics to advance . i am aiming to learn all stuff related to selenium within 2 days , also is this possible ?

Comment: Personally I prefer python, but always it's a choice between the languages based on the language used by your dev team and team comfort. You can get the important and regular actions in 2 days but not everything related to selenium, which you will get with practice/experience. All the best thought!! cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. i really appreciate that . thanks again and have a good day .

Comment: can you please have a look on this problem : [This Question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908435/java-selenium-cant-login-gmail)