# Can't Login into Gmail Using Selenium VB.NET (Couldn’t sign you in)

Tags: .net, selenium, browser, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm Getting

[image: error]

I tried different solutions.

[Solution 1](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5855)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908435/java-selenium-cant-login-gmail)

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602974/gmail-is-blocking-login-via-automation-selenium)

[Solution 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117232/selenium-google-login-block)

But could not fix it. Is there any other way to fix it?

```
Dim driverService As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
dim driver = New ChromeDriver(driverService, chromeOptions)
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize()
driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies()
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin")

        Try

            Dim nameInput = driver.FindElementById("identifierId")

            If nameInput IsNot Nothing And nameInput.Displayed Then
                nameInput.SendKeys("xyz@gmail.com")
            End If

            Thread.Sleep(4000)

            Dim submitButton = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/div/button")

            If submitButton IsNot Nothing And submitButton.Displayed Then
                submitButton.Click()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Code has been added.